# accumulo is unable to load tablets

Tags: hadoop, accumulo

Accumulo is unable to load,delete or create a new tables.My default user is root. Master and the tablet server and zookeeper is alive.
Earlier i tried to solve this by re-initializing accumulo with accululo init but still error persists.
I m getting below exception in accumulo logs:

```
Got loadTablet message from unauthenticatable user: !SYSTEM  
2017/03/27 12:06:20,355 tserver:orkash2 11  
ERROR   
Got message from a service with a mismatched configuration. Please ensure a compatible configuration.
    ThriftSecurityException(user:!SYSTEM, code:BAD_CREDENTIALS)
        at org.apache.accumulo.server.security.SecurityOperation.authenticate(SecurityOperation.java:173)
        at org.apache.accumulo.server.security.AuditedSecurityOperation.authenticate(AuditedSecurityOperation.java:663)
        at org.apache.accumulo.server.security.SecurityOperation.canPerformSystemActions(SecurityOperation.java:452)
        at org.apache.accumulo.server.security.AuditedSecurityOperation.canPerformSystemActions(AuditedSecurityOperation.java:298)
        at org.apache.accumulo.tserver.TabletServer$ThriftClientHandler.checkPermission(TabletServer.java:1383)
        at org.apache.accumulo.tserver.TabletServer$ThriftClientHandler.loadTablet(TabletServer.java:1433)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.accumulo.core.trace.wrappers.RpcServerInvocationHandler.invoke(RpcServerInvocationHandler.java:46)
        at org.apache.accumulo.server.rpc.RpcWrapper$1.invoke(RpcWrapper.java:74)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.loadTablet(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.accumulo.core.tabletserver.thrift.TabletClientService$Processor$loadTablet.getResult(TabletClientService.java:2633)
        at org.apache.accumulo.core.tabletserver.thrift.TabletClientService$Processor$loadTablet.getResult(TabletClientService.java:2619)
        at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
        at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
        at org.apache.accumulo.server.rpc.TimedProcessor.process(TimedProcessor.java:63)
        at org.apache.thrift.server.AbstractNonblockingServer$FrameBuffer.invoke(AbstractNonblockingServer.java:516)
        at org.apache.accumulo.server.rpc.CustomNonBlockingServer$1.run(CustomNonBlockingServer.java:78)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at org.apache.accumulo.fate.util.LoggingRunnable.run(LoggingRunnable.java:35)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)   

Caller doesn't have permission to load a tablet
    ThriftSecurityException(user:!SYSTEM, code:BAD_CREDENTIALS)
        at org.apache.accumulo.server.security.SecurityOperation.authenticate(SecurityOperation.java:173)
        at org.apache.accumulo.server.security.AuditedSecurityOperation.authenticate(AuditedSecurityOperation.java:663)
        at org.apache.accumulo.server.security.SecurityOperation.canPerformSystemActions(SecurityOperation.java:452)
        at org.apache.accumulo.server.security.AuditedSecurityOperation.canPerformSystemActions(AuditedSecurityOperation.java:298)
        at org.apache.accumulo.tserver.TabletServer$ThriftClientHandler.checkPermission(TabletServer.java:1383)
        at org.apache.accumulo.tserver.TabletServer$ThriftClientHandler.loadTablet(TabletServer.java:1433)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.accumulo.core.trace.wrappers.RpcServerInvocationHandler.invoke(RpcServerInvocationHandler.java:46)
        at org.apache.accumulo.server.rpc.RpcWrapper$1.invoke(RpcWrapper.java:74)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.loadTablet(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.accumulo.core.tabletserver.thrift.TabletClientService$Processor$loadTablet.getResult(TabletClientService.java:2633)
        at org.apache.accumulo.core.tabletserver.thrift.TabletClientService$Processor$loadTablet.getResult(TabletClientService.java:2619)
        at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
        at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
        at org.apache.accumulo.server.rpc.TimedProcessor.process(TimedProcessor.java:63)
        at org.apache.thrift.server.AbstractNonblockingServer$FrameBuffer.invoke(AbstractNonblockingServer.java:516)
        at org.apache.accumulo.server.rpc.CustomNonBlockingServer$1.run(CustomNonBlockingServer.java:78)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at org.apache.accumulo.fate.util.LoggingRunnable.run(LoggingRunnable.java:35)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

When trying to create tables from shell, shell exception is:

```
[impl.ThriftTransportPool] WARN : Thread "shell" stuck on IO to host1:9999 (0) for at least 120061 ms
```

Accumulo dashboard logs is:
`Thread "tracer" stuck on IO to host1:9999 (0) for at least 120062 ms`

Answer (score 1):

Check your configuration. The log message indicates that there is a problem with the internal system user performing operations. The internal system user uses credentials derived from the configuration (such as the `instance.secret` field). Make sure your configuration is identical across all nodes in your cluster.